# Body part of POST Http request is null

Tags: ios, .net, post, afnetworking-2, frombodyattribute

I'm using `AFNetworking` framework to send some data to the `.Net` backend. I'm using `POST:parameters:success:failure:` method.

The .net backend is reading data using the `FromBody` attribute

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string objCourseData, string securityToken, string appVer, string deviceDesc, string deviceOSDesc)
```

but it receives it as null. I've tried with PHP and I can see my body data in the `$_POST` object (I can't see it in the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` though). What could be the problem?

The data I'm sending is JSON object.

Comment: What data are you trying to post, isn't it JSON?

Comment: Did you try with NSURLSession and NSURLConnection before? It's pretty simple.

Comment: I haven't I'm new to this ios ... programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use AFNetworking, but using native code is simple:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.urlpost.com";

//setting request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:5];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//setting post body with JSON data
NSMutableDictionary *postDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
//set the data of your json
[postDictionary setValue:@"some value" forKey:@"myKey"];
NSError *jsonError;

//transform NSMutableDictionary in JSON data
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&jsonError];

if (!jsonError) {
    //set POST body
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
}

//Here is the code for the post:
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        //No errors, post done
        NSLog(@"POST done!");
    } else { 
       //error handling here 
    }
}] resume];
```

Comment: I've accepted this as it gave me clear access to details of the request, I'm sure similar can be achieved with `AFNetworking` but failed to find resolution.

Comment: I haven't used AFNetworking, but after set the request, you just need to do the download as you have been doing